# R Shiny not plotting some ggplot2 layers

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, visualization, data-visualization

I already faced one really weird problem and I am facing another. I have already "solved" the first one but I mention it here as well because I do not mean it is "solved" in the right way.

By the way, just a note here: **everything is working fine in console, just Shiny is somehow bugged** or I dont know.

### **Problem nr. 1:**

I styled my UI in a proper way, I won't post it here because it would be long and it is irrelevant. The important part of the UI is `plotOutput('survival_curve', height = '750px')`. Also there a few inputs as you will see in the code.

So I now I can work on the code content in `shinyServer()` function. So I do the following (**ATTENTION** - I had to translate some variable names in code from Czech to English. So I hope did not do any mistake nor I did not forgot to translate some variable names:

```
shinyServer(
    ...
    ...
    ...
    output$survival_curve <- renderPlot(
        curve_year_bottom <- input$survival_curve_input_years[1]
        curve_year_top <- input$survival_curve_input_years[2]
        curve_group_after_years <- input$survival_curve_input_group_after

        data_survival_curve <- data[data$transplant_year %in% seq(curve_year_bottom, curve_year_top) &
                                !is.na(data$survival_time) &
                                data$survival_time >= 0,]
        data_survival_curve$time_period <- cut(as.numeric(data_survival_curve$transplant_year),
                                               seq(curve_year_bottom, curve_year_top, curve_group_after_years),
                                               include.lowest = T)

        surv_obj <- Surv(data_survival_curve$survival_time/365,data_survival_curve$patient_died)
        fit <- survfit(surv_obj ~ time_period, data = data_survival_curve)

        survival_curve_plt <- ggsurvplot(fit,
                                         linetype = c('solid'),
                                         ggtheme = theme_bw(),
                                         surv.scale = 'percent',
                                         xlab = 'Years',
                                         ylab = '%',
                                         censor = FALSE,
                                         break.x.by = 1,
                                         break.y.by = 0.1) +
                                geom_dl(aes(label = time_period), method = list("last.points"), cex = 0.8)

    print(survival_curve_plt)
  }
)
```

Ok now, when I start my server like this, I get an error saying: `Error: object 'data_survival_curve' not found`. It is completely weird right so I try to define a variable `data_survival_curve` before `shinyServer()` is called. So I do that in `var.R` script, `source(var.R)` and Voila!, it seems that the object was found but now I am getting another error: `Error: object 'surv_obj' not found`. This error comes from `survfit()` from the first argument. So I repeat the same - I predefine all the variables that are passed into `ggsurvplot()` and again - Voila! - it works! Can anyone tell me how to get rid of this? It seems like some functions can not find these temporary variables created in `shinyServer()`.

---

### Problem nr. 2

At first I thought it is the same kind of problem as the first one was. Nope, it is not.

So, I explain. Look at these lines of code - they are the same as in the first code snippet:

```
survival_curve_plt <- ggsurvplot(fit,
                                 linetype = c('solid'),
                                 ggtheme = theme_bw(),
                                 surv.scale = 'percent',
                                 xlab = 'Years',
                                 ylab = '%',
                                 censor = FALSE,
                                 break.x.by = 1,
                                 break.y.by = 0.1) +
                        geom_dl(aes(label = time_period), method = list("last.points"), cex = 0.8)
```

If I run this code with predefined variables in **command line**, graph is perfectly plotted and I am happy. It looks like this:
[image]
*Roky == Years

Now I come to a problem when I run this code in my `shinyServer()`. The layer created by `geom_dl()` (the labels at the end of the each line) is not plotted and I do not know what to do with that.

I think Shiny is somehow bugged. I do not really see problems in my code.

### EDIT:

Test data:

```
data <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,3,4,5,6), patient_died = c(1,0,0,1,1,0), survival_time = c(21, 378, 3356, 7652, 3321, 324), transplant_year = c(2002, 2016, 2018, 2017, 2016, 2017))
```

This is how my graph for which was generated by the following lines of code for test data should look like on website created by Shiny:

```
data_survival_curve$time_period <- cut(as.numeric(data_survival_curve$transplant_year),
                        seq(2002, 2020, 2),
                        include.lowest = T)
surv_obj <- Surv(data_survival_curve$survival_time/365,data_survival_curve$patient_died)
fit <- survfit(surv_obj ~ time_period, data = data_survival_curve)

ggsurvplot(fit,
           linetype = c('solid'),
           ggtheme = theme_bw(),
           surv.scale = 'percent',
           xlab = 'Roky',
           ylab = '%',
           censor = FALSE,
           break.x.by = 1,
           break.y.by = 0.1) +
    geom_dl(aes(label = time_period), method = list("last.points"), cex = 0.8)
```

[image]

And this is how it really looks like on my Shiny website:
[image]

I am using the following packages in my application:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(survival)
library(rms)
library(survminer)
library(ggfortify)
library(directlabels)
```

Comment: The return value is of `ggsurvplot` is of the class `ggsurvplot`. You need to convert it to a `ggplot` object and then print the converted object to make it work with `shiny`. The reason this works in the command line is because `print` is a generic function

Comment: I do the same `print()` `shinyServer()` function. Or I see that incorrectly?

Comment: Try replacing `print(survival_curve_plt)` with `print(survival_curve_plt$plot)` is what I meant.

Comment: I havent been at laptop yet so I could not try it yet but I still do not understand why shiny should accept this and it should work if my code does not work? Or is there written anywhere that shiny does not plot ggsurvplot objects? Can you explain me this, please? @Gregor de Cillia

Comment: @GregordeCillia it does not work. The labels still does not get printed.

Comment: Please provide some test data and list all the packaes you are using. As is, I can't do more than guess how your output looks like and what is wrong with it.

Comment: @GregordeCillia I edited my question. Added this stuff at the end.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried your test data and didn't run into any issues if I convert the output of `ggsurvplot` into a `ggplot` object right away.

Can you pleaso tell me whether the labels are visible when you execute this code?

```
library(shiny)
library(survival)
library(survminer)
library(directlabels)

data <- data.frame(
  id = c(1,2,3,4,5,6), patient_died = c(1,0,0,1,1,0), 
  survival_time = c(21, 378, 3356, 7652, 3321, 324), 
  transplant_year = c(2002, 2016, 2018, 2017, 2016, 2017)
)
data_survival_curve <- data
data_survival_curve$time_period <- cut(as.numeric(data_survival_curve$transplant_year),
                    seq(2002, 2020, 2),
                    include.lowest = T)

surv_obj <- Surv(data_survival_curve$survival_time/365, data_survival_curve$patient_died)
fit <- survfit(surv_obj ~ time_period, data = data_survival_curve)

ggsp <- ggsurvplot(fit, linetype = c('solid'), ggtheme = theme_bw(),
           surv.scale = 'percent', xlab = 'Roky', ylab = '%', censor = FALSE,
           break.x.by = 1, break.y.by = 0.1) 
ggsp2 <- ggsp$plot + geom_dl(aes(label = time_period), method = list("last.points"), 
                             cex = 0.8)

shinyApp(
  fluidPage(plotOutput("plot")),
  function(input, output, session){
    output$plot <- renderPlot({ggsp2})
  }
)
```

However, If I try to execute the code the way you posted it (skipping the `$plot`), I get the following error.

```
ggsp2 <- ggsp$plot + geom_dl(aes(label = time_period), method = list("last.points"), 
                             cex = 0.8)
```

> Error in ggsp + geom_dl(aes(label = time_period), method = list("last.points"),  : 
>     non-numeric argument to binary operator
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   Incompatible methods ("+.ggsurv", "+.gg") for "+"

This makes sense to me since the output of `ggsurvplot` is in fact of class `ggsurvplot`

```
class(ggsp)
## [1] "ggsurvplot" "ggsurv"     "list"
```

To be honest, I'm quite puzzled by the fact that you didn't get similar error messages. I downloaded the latest CRAN versions of the packages above except `ggplot2`, where I use the development version (`2.2.1.9000`).

Comment: Now, the way I edited your code, it works. When I rewrote plot code in my application to this structure:
`ggsp <- ggsurvplot(fit, linetype = c('solid'), ggtheme = theme_bw(),
           surv.scale = 'percent', xlab = 'Roky', ylab = '%', censor = FALSE,
           break.x.by = 1, break.y.by = 0.1) 
ggsp2 <- ggsp$plot + geom_dl(aes(label = time_period), method = list("last.points"), 
                             cex = 0.8)` it still does not work anyway. I think that there are few other crucial lines of code in my application that differs from yours. Can we exchange any contact and discuss?

Comment: Ye, I know what is the problem. You set `data_survival_curve$time_period` before shinyApp starts. I set this in shinyApp function and this causes problems. When you move this line `data_survival_curve$time_period <- cut(as.numeric(data_survival_curve$transplant_year),
                    seq(2002, 2020, 2),
                    include.lowest = T)` to the function in 2nd argument of `shinyApp()`, you will see that it does not work. I have to do it this way because I have to set `time_period` from user input - it is dynamically generated.